# Polymer 3 - Using stylesFromTemplate

Tags: polymer

I'm a novice using Polymer 3 and need to get styles from an element. Can anyone show me a real world example of how to use stylesFromTemplate? I'm struggling.

```
stylesFromTemplate(template: !HTMLTemplateElement, baseURI: string)
```

For example, using Polymer Starter Kit (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-starter-kit), a function in my-app.js that gets the styles from my-view1.js - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go update the `_pageChanged` method of the my-app component with the following:

```
//Dont´forget to import the function
import { stylesFromTemplate } from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/style-gather.js';

_pageChanged(page) {
    import(`./my-${ page }.js`).then((viewModule) => {
        let view = new viewModule.default();
        console.log(stylesFromTemplate(view._template, window.location));
    });
}
```

Don´t forget to update `my-view1.js`, `my-view2.js`, `my-view3.js`, `my-view404.js` by making these js module export the webcomponents classes as default

```
export default class MyView1 extends PolymerElement ...
```